# PHP - google vision API - Class not found

Tags: php, google-vision

I get this error message while trying to use google vision API

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
```

I'm using xampp on windows. I installed Google api using composer (as admin)

```
composer require google/cloud-vision
```

I also run (as admin)

```
composer install
composer update
```

google cloud sdk is installed.

this is my code

```
<?php
require 'C:\Users\MyUser\vendor\autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

$path = 'caption.jpg';

$vision = new VisionClient([
    'projectId' => 'my-project-numbers',
    'keyFilePath' => 'my-key.json'
]);

// Annotate an image, detecting faces.
$image = $vision->image(
    fopen($path, 'r'),
    ['text']
);

$tadaa = $vision->annotate($image);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tadaa->text());
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: This may be path issue of autoload.php

Try to make a folder of project & then run composer require google/cloud-vision in it.

Comment: used cmd , cd to C:\xampp\htdocs where my index.php and the other files are and run the command. It did install stuff, but the error still stands

Comment: Which version of  google/cloud-vision you've installed?

Comment: For the latest version use 
# imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

for more please follow this link
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-php

Comment: from composer.json, the version is "google/cloud-vision": "^1.2"

Comment: using
require  __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
just like in the example from the link, result: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VisionClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Comment: can you please share you index.php code?

Comment: it's the code I wrote above, that's all I have in index,php

Comment: Please use this
 new ImageAnnotatorClient(); instead of VisionClient();

Comment: # imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

# instantiates a client
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, I would recommend to use this php client library:

```
# imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
```

[Quickstart: Using client libraries Vision Api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-php)

Comment: gives similar error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VisionClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

In somes cases, the problem seems related to permissions. In a development server I had the same problem reported from @thepepp, but I could fix it changing the permissions on the `vendor` folder.

> chmod 775 * -R

Answer (score 0):

Using code from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

the following is index.php

```
<?php
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;

use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

$path = 'caption.jpg';

    $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

    # annotate the image
    $image = file_get_contents($path);
    $response = $imageAnnotator->textDetection($image);
    $texts = $response->getTextAnnotations();

    printf('%d texts found:' . PHP_EOL, count($texts));
    foreach ($texts as $text) {
        print($text->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);

        # get bounds
        $vertices = $text->getBoundingPoly()->getVertices();
        $bounds = [];
        foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
            $bounds[] = sprintf('(%d,%d)', $vertex->getX(), $vertex->getY());
        }
        print('Bounds: ' . join(', ', $bounds) . PHP_EOL);
    }

    $imageAnnotator->close();

?>
```

I still get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8
```

this is composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-vision": "^1.2"
    }
}
```